# Protect Mule api from XSS attack

Tags: mule, xss

Based on security team recommendation , we have two API one in mule 3 and one in Mule 4

Both have HTTP listeners for exposed endpoints with POST payload.

One API ( Mule 3 ) interacts with Salesforce and gets back JSON response

Mule 4 API interacts with a 3rd party system via SOAP and gets XML response .

Securty team has advised that all incoming requests to mule ( HTTP Listener ) need to prevent bad data ( example : containing  tags , there are are various other things to be looked for )

Similarly when we get response back ( Salesforce JSON , 3rd party SOAP response ) , we need to check and validate response .

Am wondering how to go about it for both HTTP Listener and also for HTTP Request in mule ?
Should this be done via a Dataweave script right after HTTP listener to validate incoming request ? and in case of HTTP Request right after receiving response ?

I am looking for ideas on how to go about it please ?
This link is quite generic and does not provide any concrete details:
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Cross-Site-Scripting-XSS-Prevention-in-Mule-application

Comment: What data is the HTTP Listener receiving? You ask how to validate it but you didn't provide details. Are you familiar with XSS attacks? Do you understand how they apply to your APIs?

Comment: I think there are many factors that needs to be considered for this? What is the deployment model you are following, is it on cloudhub / onprem etc? Do you use API manager or maybe are there any other security layers in your architecture, like a WAF or something. Sure you can write the validations in your Mule code itself, but it is not always necessary that it is the correct approach